# how much should I charge for recording and editing 800 lines of text?

Tags: dialogue-recording, rates

Client is a corporation in Europe.
The project is an instructional/safety video.

I pretty much got all equipment needed, an actor willing to read and a studio.
Just need to set a good price for the actual work on per hour basis.

need a quick answer ;)
any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much do you think you would want to pay for your audio?

Union rates in some areas are around 500-800 dollars a day for an experienced editor or mixer - don't quote me, as this is that last I remember a reference to "the paycheck." If anyone knows, chime in.

You also have which currency conversion to consider.

I feel  charge concordant with your skill, and it seems to work out.

Sounds like a good VO session for sure - Good luck! Get some good takes

Comment: thx for quick answer. around 500$ seems reasonable. I'll maybe make it litle less, to be more competitive ;)


Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it:

figure out your hourly rate.
estimate how long it will take to record everything.
allot 2 or 3x your record time for editing naming and output
have a line item for archival and delivery

add and done.

Comment: @Rene thx for tip. I'll sure need more time for editing etc.